# Outlook 2013 VBA VBE F8 Sometimes Doesn't Work

Tags: vba, outlook, vbe

When debugging code in the Outlook 2013 VBA Visual Basic Editor, sometimes the function key **F8 Step Into** is totally ignored.  The Debug Toolbar Step Into works just fine.  When this occurs it seems to go on for many lines of code, and then sometimes the F8 key will start to work again.

Comment: I tried to add an outlook-vbe tag, but I don't have sufficient reputation points.  There seem to be sufficient issues with the vba editor that a vbe tag is warranted.

Answer (score 0):

Most keyboards have the **F Lock** button which blocks all **F** buttons on the keyboard.